# Varying n_neighbors in scikit-learn KNN regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, knn

I am using scikit-learn's KNN regressor to fit a model to a large dataset with `n_neighbors = 100-500`. Given the nature of the data, some parts (think: sharp delta-function like peaks) are better fit with fewer neighbors (`n_neighbors ~ 20-50`) so that the peaks are not smoothed out. The location of these peaks are known (or can be measured).

Is there a way to vary the `n_neighbors` parameter?

I could fit two models and stitch them together, but that would be inefficient. It would be preferable to either prescribe 2-3 values for `n_neighbors` or, worse, send in an list of `n_neighbors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not.  In part, this is due to some algebraic assumptions that the relationship is symmetric: A is a neighbour to B iff B is a neighbour to A.  If you give different **k** values, you're guaranteed to break that symmetry.

I think the major reason is simply that the algorithm is simpler with a fixed quantity of neighbors, yielding better results *in general*.  You have a specific case that KNN doesn't fit so well.

I suggest that you stitch together your two models, switching dependent on the imputed second derivative.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that was the case. I did not know about the symmetry postulate but it makes sense.